# Determine what started it

Tags: java, jar, executable

I have an interesting question today. Im trying to create a program that only starts if it is executed by a program, but will error if it is started by the user. Whats some code I can use to do this?

Comment: can you please elaborate with some code example?

Comment: You can check the parent process and see if its a shell.

Answer (score 0):

If by `user` you mean DIRECT user interaction:

You can control where a user may start the program from, e.g. button click. You may also control where another program may start the program from. So any direct issued command from a user should throw an exception; for example, when said button is clicked `throw new Exception("I detect user");`

Answer (score 0):

Make the entry point something incompatible with

`public void main ( String [ ] args ) throws Exception`

like

`int entryPoint ( String name )`